# curl: (7) couldn't connect to host What is wrong in my settings?

Tags: linux, shell, curl

When I run command:

```
$ curl http://localhost:9201
```

I get this error:

```
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

Next when I run command `curl` with verbose flag i.e.:

```
$ curl -v http://localhost:9201
```

It ends up with error:

```
* About to connect() to localhost port 9201 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

I really cannot understand why this error happens. What is wrong in my settings? How can I fix this?

Comment: run 'netstat -pan', check whether port 9201 is listening

Comment: @yudongshen 9201 is not listening.Hos should I do?

Comment: start your web server, if failure, check it's log, try fix it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, your server is not listening on port `9201`.

You need to first verify that if your server has successfully started listening on your designated port. As [yudong shen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9031481/yudong-shen) suggested, you may use `netstat` command to verify this.

For example:

To list all the `<ip:port>` pairs along with their state and their respective process:

```
$ netstat -anp
```

Observe the `Local address`, `State` and `PID/Program name` columns to identify your process and its designated `<ip:port>` with state.

To check if the designated port is used by a process irrespective of its state:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep :9201
```

To make sure that the port is open for listening:

```
$ netstat -anp | grep LISTEN | grep :9201
```

You may also use a REST Client such as [Google Chrome's Postman](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/postman/fhbjgbiflinjbdggehcddcbncdddomop?hl=en) to interact with your web server from a GUI.

Answer (score 0):

The service you're trying to connect to being unavailable is the first check you should make. However, in my case, it was running and got a weirder error:

```
$ curl -i -X POST http://127.0.0.1:12345/command -d 'some JSON here'
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:31280; Connection refused
```

Why the wrong port?! Well `man curl` does describe the `-v` flag, so let's use it:

```
$ curl -i -v -X POST http://localhost:12345/command -d 'some JSON here'
* About to connect() to proxy 127.0.0.1 port 31280 (#0)
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connection refused
* Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:31280; Connection refused
* Closing connection 0
curl: (7) Failed connect to 127.0.0.1:31280; Connection refused
```

And now we can facepalm ourselves for not having the proxy up.

Answer (score 0):

Another reason could be misconfiguration in `/etc/hosts`; if there is no line similar to

```
127.0.0.1 localhost
```

`localhost` won't be resolved to `127.0.0.1`.

In my case I wasn't able to open host served by Apache.

My cURL was

```
root@myserver:~# curl -v -k --compressed -H 'Host: www.mysite.com' 

http://localhost/
* About to connect() to localhost port 80 (#0)
*   Trying ::1... Connection refused
* couldn't connect to host
* Closing connection #0
curl: (7) couldn't connect to host
```

This response misses

```
*   Trying 127.0.0.1... connected
```

Adding `127.0.0.1 localhost` in `/etc/hosts` fixed the issue.