# curl connection refused with thingsboard HTTP API

Tags: rest, http, curl, virtual-machine, thingsboard

**Details:**

I am trying to post telemetry to thingsboard using the following command, as in the [HTTP API Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/reference/http-api/):

```
curl -v -X POST -d "{\"temperature\": 25}" 122.20.192.14/api/v1/Ll6Pfoi5MosB5bC4nUxb/telemetry --header "Content-Type:application/json"
```

The ip address is the address of my virtual machine running Ubuntu 20.04, with Thingsboard services running and demo data loaded on premise as per the [Installation Guide](https://thingsboard.io/docs/user-guide/install/ubuntu/).I am submitting the `curl` command from my windows bash environment, and I get the following error:

```
 curl(7) Failed to connect to 122.20.192.14 port 80 after 2044 ms: Connection refused
```

I am able to run the equivalent command (with `http://localhost:8080` replacing the ip address of course) from my virtual machine's terminal without error.

I have tried using `ss -anp | grep LISTEN | grep :80`, and it tells me something like this:

`tcp LISTEN 0 100 *:8080 *:*` *(I don't know how to copy paste from my vm, but absent the formatting it's the response it gave me)*

I think this means it is listening on that port, so why is the connection refused?

I've looked at similar posts regarding both [sending data through HTTP to Thingsboard](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62030676/how-to-send-data-to-thingsboard-via-http) and [curl error(7)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48352370/curl-7-couldnt-connect-to-host-what-is-wrong-in-my-settings), but haven't been able to resolve this issue.

*(Note that I have randomly edited the ip address and device access token from their true values so they aren't publicly available, so if you identify a problem with those specific sequences, that's probably not the issue.)*

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the firewall? It might happen because the firewall has not allowed port 80. Try `sudo ufw allow 80` and `sudo ufw reload`. Please do tell me what happens afterwards.

Comment: Good call. It still says connection refused, but that was a smart thing to try. I even tried running the command from the virtual machine this time, but it still says connection refused, even though the request would have come from its own ip address.